# standalone react-native module with cocoapods dependency

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, cocoapods

I have successfully built a react-native module within a `react-native int` project. Now I want to extract this module (standalone i.e `react-native-my-custom-module`) to its own repo, so I can reuse it in other projects and open-source it. I tried using https://github.com/frostney/react-native-create-library to create this standalone react-native module. However, the react-native module has a dependency on external SDK(installed using CocoaPods i.e `pod 'Firebase/Core'`) and due to this, I believe it is Breaking.

**What I Tried:**

#### In the standalone Module Repo

- Moved module logic(i.e `.swift` `.h`(header-bridge), `.m`) files
- added `$(SRCROOT)/../../../ios/Pods/**` to the Header search Paths
- No Pods dependencies(i.e no Podfile, Pods etc)(It made sense to not include Pods in the `<react-native-my-custom-module>` and instead install Pods in the Project.)

#### In the Project

- `yarn add <react-native-my-custom-module>`
- `react-native link <react-native-my-custom-module>`
- added `pod 'Firebase/Core'` in Pod file and ran `pod install`

**Tried to Build project but get an error that at the line `import firebase` *Error*: `No such module 'Firebase'`**

Additionally, If I comment out the import statement `import firebase` and the code using the External SDK, the remaining methods and logic in the Native Module works(confirmed with JS).

**Update:** I also tried to install `<react-native-my-custom-module>` using CocoaPods  instead on `react-native link` i.e by adding the following in my Project Pod file

```
pod 'RNCustomModule', path: '../node_modules/MyCustomReactNativeMidule/ios/RNCustomModule.podspec'
```

The Pods successfully get installed but I still get the same *Error*: `No such module 'Firebase'`

Comment: This is something that I’m going to be doing shortly so I am interested to know how it is solved.

Comment: I've been having a look into it and I think it is possible though you have to use git submodules.

Comment: shouldn't it be simple as using Pods from the project? Can you share your findings

Comment: I haven’t found any documentation on it. I’ve just been looking at other repos. I’m not even sure if it is submodules. It looks like it. If you look at this repo https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image in the iOS/Vendors folder it links directly to the SDWebImage repo. Alternatively you could create a podspec for your repo and add it as a dependency to that.

Comment: @Andrew, I think the fast-image do use submodules. There is .gitmodules file under the project, which dependent on SDWebImage.

Comment: @jasan Have you found any solution for the above?